# How to get the current locale in apostrophecms in a nunjucks file using apostrophe-workflow

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm just starting with apostrophcms and apostrophe-workflow so sorry if that looks obvious.
I'm currently trying to add a language dropdown menu in my header. I get it working in the way that all locales are present in the dropdown but what I try to do is to have the current language shown and others hiden in the dropdown, code may be more explicit:

```html
 <ul class="navbar-nav nav-flex-icons">

          <a class="nav-link dropdown-item" href="#" id="lang-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <pre>{{ apos.i18n | dump}}</pre>
            {# I WANT THE CURRENT LANGUAGE HERE but I don't know where to find it #}
          </a>

          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="lang-dropdown">
            {% for localization in apos
              .workflow
              .localizations() %}
                  {% if localization.name != CURRENT_LOCALE_I_CANT_FIND %}
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ localization._url | build({ workflowLocale: localization.workflowLocale }) }}">
                      <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-{{localization.workflowLocale.split('-')[1] | lower}}"></span>
                      {{ localization.label }}
                    </a>
                  {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </ul>
```

I hope you can help and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the active language with `apos.workflow.lang()` This is mentioned in the README in relation to the HTML `lang` attribute, but it can be used for setting an active item in the switcher as well.

I used this recently on a project. Similar to yours, the `ul` is turned into a drop-down selector using CSS and JS and the `button` toggles it open, but also is displaying the active language. The first loop and conditional is used to get the readable label for the active language, since `lang()` returns the language/locale code.

```html
{% set lang = '' %}
{% set activeLocale = apos.workflow.lang() %}
{% for l in apos.workflow.localizations() %}
  {% if l.workflowLocale === activeLocale %}
    {% set lang = l.label %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
<button type="button" data-role="lang-toggle">
  <span>{{ lang }}</span>
</button>
<ul data-role="lang-list">
  {% for locale in apos.workflow.localizations() %}
    {% if locale.workflowLocale !== activeLocale %}
      <li>
        <a href="{{ locale._url | build({ workflowLocale: locale.workflowLocale }) }}" >{{ locale.label }}</a>
      </li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank's for answering, I actually used the `apos.workflow.lang()` and I thinked to it to do what you proposed. I will use it for now and accept your answer.  
But There's still one thing I was thinking of: In a previous project where I was using node `i18n` and express, I added a middleware that was setting in the `res.locals` the `i18n.getLocale()` and `i18n.getLocales()` thus in my njk files I was just doing `getLocale()`... It's off topic but do you think there's a chance I can do that here with apostrophe because I find it way cleaner. Thank you again!

Comment: After a lot of object logging/searching i found what I was looking for to use with your answer: it's here: `{% data.global.workflowLocale %}` which is the current locale (so not only lang like `en` but the full name like `en-us`)

Comment: Even better! We need to get that in the documentation.