# Get apostrophe-workflow localizations to work for a website with multiple blogs

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have an ApostropheCMS project that has multiple blogs with articles in each of them. For this purpose, I created a separate module for each blog and separate blog pages, to hold the page and article templates (not very DRY, but I understood that this is the only solution to have multiple blogs, if you don't want to rely on tags).

The website also has a navigation macro that contains a language picker macro, in which the user is shown the current locale and can select a different locale to have the page load in another language. The component looks like this, as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60447641/how-to-get-the-current-locale-in-apostrophecms-in-a-nunjucks-file-using-apostrop) Stack Overflow answer:

```
{% macro render() %}
{% set lang = '' %}
{% set activeLocale = apos.workflow.lang() %}
{% for l in apos.workflow.localizations() %}
  {% if l.workflowLocale === activeLocale %}
    {% set lang = l.label %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
<button type="button" data-role="lang-toggle">
  <span>{{ lang }}</span>
</button>
<ul data-role="lang-list">
  {% for locale in apos.workflow.localizations() %}
    {% if locale.workflowLocale !== activeLocale %}
      <li>
        <a href="{{ locale._url | build({ workflowLocale: locale.workflowLocale }) }}" >{{ locale.label }}</a>
      </li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endmacro %}
```

On the **Home** page, it works like a charm, I can see the current language on the button and the other languages in the drop-down list.

The problem is that, when I create a page of a different type, for example `Blog One Index`, `apostrophe-workflow` doesn't seem to be able to retrieve the docs anymore, and so it is not able to construct the `localizations` object anymore (there are pages/articles created already under that blog).

I have to admit I'm new to ApostropheCMS and Mongo.js, so it's difficult for me to find out how exactly to solve this issue. I can only see that the method `self.getLocalizations()` inside `node_modules/apostrophe-workflow/lib/api.js` uses a criteria named `workflowGuid` to find the documents, but when I navigate from Home to the blog page, it returns 0 results.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have `replicateAcrossLocales: false` configured, as we recommend in our docs. So apart from parked pages like the home page and a few similar cases, no document automatically exists in more than one locale, and `self.getLocalizations` has no additional versions to find, other than the one in the initial language.

However if you go to that "Blog One Index" page and use the editing UI's palette menu (not a custom one) to try to pick another locale, you will be invited to create that document in the other locale, and then you will start to see another locale available in your `getLocalizations` queries.

Comment: You're correct, I missed the `replicateAcrossLocales` flag completely. I went the other way around and defined a prefix for each locale and now I construct the url to use in the dropdown by adding the prefix + the piece/page url. I might try your solution at some point, but now I'm a bit short on time.